# log4j-slf4j2-impl does not include log4j-core, is this intentional?

Tags: log4j, slf4j

I noticed that `log4j-core` has different dependency scope in the two `slf4j-impl` libraries.

Is this by design?

|  | `log4j-core` `scope` |
| --- | --- |
| `log4j-slf4j-impl` | [runtime](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/rel/2.19.0/log4j-slf4j-impl/pom.xml#L55-L59) |
| `log4j-slf4j2-impl` | [test](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/rel/2.19.0/log4j-slf4j2-impl/pom.xml#L53-L57) |

Looks like it was changed with this [commit](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/commit/8f63620875b7cc742a4c153101a875bf9df45227#diff-d3ba9956a9f81420d0be3d69477a05b505746272d548ab17404aa47f3e5946b0L56-R56), which references [LOG4J2-2975](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2975). I don't see anything that mentions why the `scope` was changed from `runtime` to `test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, removing the runtime dependency on `log4j-core` was intentional, since the `log4j-slf4j2-impl` module works with **any** implementation of the Log4j2 API.

Since version 2.17.2 at least two implementations can be used with the SLF4J-to-LOG4J2 bridge: `log4j-core` and `log4j-to-jul` (the third implementation maintained by the Log4j2 project, `log4j-to-slf4j`, can not be used for obvious reasons).

This choice was not undisputed: cf. [LOG4J2 3601](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3601) for a discussion.